# Most efficient way of storing and retrieving 3 lists of related data in python

Tags: python, django, processing-efficiency

I have a django model name, the model and the record of the model.
What is the most efficient way of storing and retrieving them.
I was thinking of 3 separate lists or a dictionary with the model name as the key and tuple containing the model and record as the value.
Any other options?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did some timings on storing and retrieving data from Lists and dictionaries of tuples and lists appear to be faster.
Results

List took: 0.005285699999999949 seconds

Dict took: 0.10288800000000009 seconds

Code used

```
start_time = time.process_time()
model_names = []
models = []
records = []
nbr_of_interations = 10000
for i in range(nbr_fixed_models):
    model_names.append(fixed_models[i].__name__)
    models.append(model_names[i])
    records.append(fixed_models[i](name=generate_random_string(50)))

for _ in range(nbr_of_interations):
    model_to_find = fixed_models[random.randint(0,nbr_fixed_models-1)]
    model_loc = model_names.index(model_to_find.__name__)
    if hasattr(models[model_loc], 'name'):
        records[model_loc].name = generate_random_string(50)
print(f'List took: {time.process_time() - start_time} seconds')

start_time = time.process_time()
model_details =\
    {fixed_models[i].__name__: (fixed_models[i], fixed_models[i](name=generate_random_string(50)))
     for i in range(nbr_fixed_models)}

for _ in range(nbr_of_interations):
    model_to_find = fixed_models[random.randint(0,nbr_fixed_models-1)].__name__
    if hasattr(model_details[model_to_find][0], 'name'):
        model_details[model_to_find][1].name = generate_random_string(50)
print(f'Dict took: {time.process_time() - start_time} seconds')
```

Comment: Anyone know why the lists are faster?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).